# Rails - Multiple Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to use a select tag to save multiple nested children in a parent.

**This is the error I'm looking at**

```
Couldn't find all UserLocations with IDs (1, 2) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

I have the following setup under `Rails 4` and `Devise`:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_locations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_locations, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**UserLocation** (locations that the user has)

```
class UserLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :location
end
```

**Location** (predefined list of locations the user can choose upon)

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_locations
    has_many :users, through: :user_locations
end
```

However, when trying to save the selected `UserLocations`, they won't be saved.

**Rails Select Tag** (You can choose multiple items)

```
<%= f.select :user_location_ids, options_for_select(Location.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id ] }, @user.user_locations.collect{ |l| l.id }), {}, { multiple: true } %>
```

I have put the `user_location_ids` in my `application_controller` as `user_location_ids: []`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The solution is to overwrite the default setter method for multiple nested models `model_ids=(value)`. Do **not** use the plural of the model, e.g. `models_ids=(value)`, because that **is wrong**!

```
def user_location_ids=(value)
  for slot in value do
    unless slot == ""
      location = Location.find_by(id: slot.to_i)
      unless location.nil?
        self.user_locations << UserLocation.create(user_id: self.id, location_id: location.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```